# Conditional formatting across two sheets by search_key, range

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet file with two sheets A,B inside: A,B join Id#

**A sheet**

```
Id  120 Cost 1000  
Id  132 Cost 1500  
Id  122 Cost 1600
```

**B sheet**

```
Id  120 Cost 1100  
Id  132 Cost 1500  
Id  122 Cost 1600
```

Condition `Cost` in `A` Sheet:

Green  if `Cost`  in A = B
Red    if `Cost`  in A not= B

Thus `Cost` for `Id 120` in `SheetA` should be red.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two columns in each sheet, A for `Id` and B for `Cost`.

In Google Spreadsheets conditional formatting across sheets is not nearly as straightforward as within a single sheet, because of security and therefore authorisation. You may, for speed for example, prefer to copy the content of SheetB into SheetA to avoid that issue, or write a script instead.

However it is possible, though may be slow and does require authorisation.

Please clear any conditional formatting from SheetA ColumnsA:B, and fill ColumnB with (standard) green fill (skipping Row1 and/or any blank cells, if that suits you) then:

Select ColumnB in SheetA, Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... `Custom formula is` and

```
=vlookup(A1,IMPORTRANGE("k e y","B!A:B"),2,0)<>B1
```

with red fill and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

`k e y` above represents the unique identification code for SheetB (will look something like `1u4vq8vDne-aKMVdJQPREGOxx7n99FqIb_kuJ_bG-PzM`) and it will require a once-off authorisation.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way i Guess is to write

```
=IF((VLOOKUP(B1,B!B$1$:D$3,3,false))<>D$1,Not Same, Same)
```

in a separate column on Sheet A which will check if their values are the same. If it is not, it will display False.

Then on your column D or C in Sheet A, put in the conditional formating

```
=IF(F1="Not Same", True, False) and change the color to Red
F1 is where I've put the 1st formula
```

This is a quick and dirty fix. Might have other cleaner ways to do that.